# Why does my Java program add only half a list of numbers in a file?

Tags: java, arrays

I have a space delimited list of 36 numbers in a single line in a file that I am trying to read into an array. My program reads the entire line, but adds only 18 of the numbers. Does anyone see the reason?

Thank you.

```
    StringTokenizer st;

    try{
       BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                 new FileReader("Scores.txt"));


       String line = br.readLine();
       double avg = 0.0;
       double sum = 0.0;
       int count = 0;


       while (line!=null)
        {
               st = new StringTokenizer(line);
                    System.out.println("Total tokens : " + st.countTokens());
               for(int i = 0; i < st.countTokens(); i++)
                {
                       avg += Double.parseDouble(st.nextToken());
                       count++;
                       System.out.println("i: " + i); 
                }
            System.out.println(line);

            line = br.readLine();
       }

       br.close();
       sum = avg; 
       System.out.println("Sum: " + sum); 
       System.out.println("Count: " + count);
       avg = avg/count;
       System.out.println("Avg: " + avg);



    }catch(Exception e)
```

Comment: Did you get the value 36 for st.countTokens() and count?

Comment: What do you see when you step through the code in you debugger?

Comment: My guess is that st.countTokens() gives you the number of token left. But I would have to read the documentation and who has time for that.

Comment: Can we see the source data and the output?

Comment: @RohitJain Amazing, I was right and I never used StringTokenizer, nor read the docs.  I would use Scanner instead.

Comment: @MikeW The source data:

67 64 93 81 92 98 13 75 89 81 56 88 99 71 80 97 58 78 74 84 21 64 72 69 78 87 84 72 96 83 68 62 88 90 23 75

I'm running from the command line, and I don't have an easy way of copying/pasting the results.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I'm not running in a programming environment today, just command line. I don't know how to use the JDK CLI debugger.

Comment: I suggest you learn how to use an IDE.  They are designed to make developers more productive.  To compile and run a program is one button and the debugger is usually the button next to it. You will find the IDE can write half the code for you as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`st.countTokens()` gives the number tokens left.  When you have 18 tokens, there are 18 tokens left so you stop.  Instead of doing this I suggest you read the documentation which suggest the following pattern

```
 StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer("this is a test");
 while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
     System.out.println(st.nextToken());
 }
```

Comment: Moreover, StringTokenizer shouldn't be used anymore. Rather just use `String.split()`.

Comment: @RohitJain Or Scanner I think is better since you want to parse doubles.

Comment: Yeah of course. Scanner is far better option than BufferedReader if you need something more than just reading from stream, and dumping it somewhere.

Comment: Funny it is. The [Javadoc of StringTokenizer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) itself says that I'm legacy class. Please don't use me. :)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using `String.split()`:

```
    String[] lineNum;
    int n;
    while (line!=null)
    {
           lineNum = line.split(" ");
           n = lineNum.length;
           System.out.println("Total numbers : " + n);
           for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                   avg += Double.parseDouble(lineNum[i]);
                   System.out.println("i: " + i); 
            }
            count += n;
            System.out.println(line);
            line = br.readLine();
   }
```

Comment: I am getting an error msg: Cannot find symbol. n = lineNum.length(); symbol: method length() location: variable lineNum of type String[]

Comment: Oops:) _length()_ is not a method, write _lineNum.length_, without the parentheses. My bad.